# Why I can't use Comparator to sort primitives?

Tags: java, sorting, wrapper, autoboxing

As Java 5 have autoboxing, why I can't use Comparator to sort primitives? An `int` wouldn't be wrapped into a `Integer`?

Comment: A Comparator is defined using generics and generics don't handle primitives.  However, Arrays.sort() doesn't take Comparator... Perhaps you can illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey just studying for the SCJP exam. And wondering what's wrong with Comparator and wrapping..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Arrays.sort(..)` have dedicated overloadings for sorting primitive arrays.

If you need any special sorting rules apart from the standard ones, I'm afraid you'd have to use autoboxing. In addition to that, you'd have to transform your array to `Integer[]`, because `int[]` is not autoboxed.

And if you are not talking about arrays, but about collections - then you have no choice - collections can hold only objects.

Comment: And they don't use comparators.

Comment: My doubt is why collections can't hold primitives, if I use an int it should be wrapped into an Integer, it IS an Objects..

Comment: Collections are defines using Generics and Generics don't support primitives. You can have collections for primitives like http://trove.starlight-systems.com/ but these don't conform to the standard interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

Because you cannot parameterise a `Comparator<T>` -- or any other parameterised type -- with a primitive type.

Yes this is massively annoying... you can't make a `List<int>` or a `Map<String, boolean>` etc, and you can't write generic methods that work for both object types and primitives. You have to have dedicated methods for each of the 8 primitive types. But that's the design we've been stuck with since Java 1. Blame James Gosling ;-)

As Bozho points out, `Arrays.sort(...)` provides all the sorting methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

As of java 17 (or possibly earlier. The error message is much more informative.

```
jshell> int[] a = {1,2,3};
a ==> int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }

jshell> import java.util.Arrays;

jshell> Arrays.sort( a, (x, y)-> x - y);
|  Error:
|  no suitable method found for sort(int[],(x,y)->x - y)
|      method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
|        (inference variable T has incompatible bounds
|          equality constraints: int
|          lower bounds: java.lang.Object)
|      method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],int,int,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
|        (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
|          (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
|  Arrays.sort( a, (x, y)-> x - y);
|  ^---------^
```

So even with autoboxing, java does not correctly infer the type.