# Why is autoboxing not allowed for primitive arrays when using Arrays.sort()?

Tags: java, sorting, autoboxing

It is known that autoboxing can be computationally intensive, but it seems to me that allowing primitive arrays be autoboxed to their `Object` equivalent for sorting methods is an appropriate edge case, particularly when the values are being sorted based on some external calculation.

I had an issue earlier, where a given array of primitive `int`s needed to be sorted by the results of a calculation based on the index value.  However,`java.util.Comparator` does not allow primitive types for any implementing classes and `compare(T x, T y)` methods.

So instead of doing something like

```
public void sortRow(int row){
  Arrays.sort(this.buffer[row], new Comparator<Integer>(){  
    @Override
    public int compare(int x, int y){
      return (PhotoUtils.getBrightnessValue(x) <= PhotoUtils.getBrightnessValue(y) ? x : y;
    }
  }
}
```

I had to implement a second step:

```
public void sortRow(int row){
  Integer[] tempArray = new Integer[this.buffer[row].length];

  for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
    tempArray[i] = this.buffer[row][i];

  Arrays.sort(tempArray, new Comparator<Integer>(){  
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y){
      return (PhotoUtils.getBrightnessValue(x) <= PhotoUtils.getBrightnessValue(y) ? x : y;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558081/why-i-cant-use-comparator-to-sort-primitives

Comment: Autoboxing an array would involve creating a loop to copy the array elements.  This is much more complicated than the relatively simple logic for individual elements.  Further, auto-unboxing array elements would have several obscure complications.  For the sort case it makes more sense to have separate compare/sort routines for each of the primitive types.

Comment: If third-party libraries are fair game, with [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you could do `Collections.sort(Ints.asList(int[]), new Comparator<Integer>() { ... })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [JLS, Section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7), there are only the following specified boxing conversions, and arrays aren't involved in any of them:

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to
>   corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the
>   following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> - From type boolean to type Boolean
> - From type byte to type Byte
> - From type short to type Short
> - From type char to type Character
> - From type int to type Integer
> - From type long to type Long
> - From type float to type Float
> - From type double to type Double
> - From the null type to the null type

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is more that Type arguments can only be reference types or wildcards. [From the JLS Section 4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

> Type arguments may be either reference types or wildcards.

The `Arrays.sort(E, Comparator<? super E>)` method is a generic method where the type variable `E` is bound to the type argument used for both the array and the `Comparator`, ie. they must be the same. Primitives cannot be used with generics and therefore you cannot use arrays of primitive types.

> Why is autoboxing not allowed for primitive arrays when using
>   Arrays.sort()?

So the problem with `Arrays.sort` isn't autoboxing, it's a limitation of Generics.

For why autoboxing doesn't apply to primitives, see the other answers. Basically the JLS doesn't allow it.

Comment: From the OPs question it appears he understands this. What he actually asked was why primitive arrays were not autoboxed into an array of their wrapper type

Comment: @aaron I will review.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, your edit hit on the crux of my question.

Answer (score 0):

To Autobox a single value requires an allocation of a new primitive wrapper object. To autobox an entire array would require allocation of new primitve wrapper objects for each element of the array, as well as allocation of a new Array of references to hold the references to the new objects you just created. So it would be a lot of overhead for something that is done implicitly by a cast. What this means is that if you have a variable of type `byte[]` with size of say 1024, then you would have to allocate an array of references which are each 4-8 bytes. and allocate each of the 1024 Byte objects to fill with the values from your original array. thus you are now allocating at least 5120-9216 bytes of data in addition to the 1024 originally added to the array.

Comment: Worse than the cost would be the fact that the `Byte[]` and the `byte[]` would be separate entities, and there would be no way to ensure that changes to one would always be reflected in the other.